# IM software with real time translation?

Tags: language, instant-messaging, translation

Is there an Instant Messaging client which translates messages to and fro as they are typed/received?

So I can configure my language, (eg. English) and my correspondent's language, (eg. Spanish), and we can both have a pretty good conversation without actually knowing the other's language!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Live Messenger, with [Messenger Plus Live!](http://www.msgplus.net/), you can use the [MSNSpeakAll](http://www.msgplus.net/Downloads/Download-Details/DocumentID/8377/)  script to automatically translate both incoming and/or outgoing text.

[image]

If you are not using Live Messenger, there is a Translator plugin for Pigin (which is compatible with most IM networks)

Answer (score 1):

The [Google Wave](http://wave.google.com/) demonstration shows off an instant [translation bot](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NOHwPgMXsNY#t=51s).  It's not officially released yet, though!

Answer (score 1):

[Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/) (which is a universal IM client) has a [translator](http://code.google.com/p/pidgin-plugins/) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Live Messenger (without Plus) you can add TBot (mtbot@hotmail.com) to your contacts (more info at http://wltbot.spaces.live.com/).
To configure the translator start a chat session with the TBot and type "tbot ?" for the list of commands or "tbot change" to set your language and the destination language.
Now when you are chatting with someone speaking the destination language add Tbot to the chat and it will translate in both directions.